# Get Instagram follower_list with the new Graph API

Tags: php, instagram

With the new update some things were no longer provider to applications like the follower_list for a user.
There's a way to implement this in a new application and get the permission required to access to the follower list of any user of Instagram using the new Graph API of Facebook?